# Serialization using xml-rpc format using only the parser/writer in Java

Tags: java, xml-rpc

I am looking for a xml-rpc library for Java that allows me to marshal and unmarshal a java.util.Map or an Obect[] containing java.util.Map along with the method name to and from the xml-rpc format.  With Python I am able to do the equivalent with:

```
import xmlrpclib
d = {'key1':'val1','key2':'val2'}
xml = xmlrpclib.dumps((d,),'foo_method')
print xml
params, method_name = xmlrpclib.loads(xml)
print 'params:', params[0]
print 'method:', method_name
```

Basically I need to use only the payload format of xml-rpc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Apache XML-RPC](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/) project? IIRC, there is a MapSerializer class.

Comment: Double checked. Use `MapSerializer` to write a map, and use `MapParser` to read a map.

Comment: Thanks this is the library I was leaning towards, not quite as simple as with Python, but it is Java.

Comment: I also found [sojo](http://sojo.sourceforge.net/guide/user/object-interchange.html#XML-RPC) which looks more straightforward for String <-> Objects.